# Read CSV from Jquery and post to Server

Tags: jquery, csv, servlets, jquery-csv

I'm writing Jquery for read CSV and convert to Array then send to Server (servlet) but its shows null. 
Please rectify it

in HTML

import jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js

import http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/src/jquery.csv.js

input type "file"

button name "Click me"

script --

$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function(event){

```
var files = $('#files').prop("files");

var reader = new FileReader();

var data = new Array();

reader.readAsText(files[0]);

reader.onload = function(event){

       var csv = event.target.result;

        data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);


       };
```

$.post("UploadCSVServlet",{arraydata:data,mode:"Insert"},

function(data) {

```
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
```

});

});
});

In Servlet :

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("enter upload servlet");
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    //resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    String jsresponse="No Message";

       try
        {
        String arrayData[] = req.getParameterValues("arraydata[]");
        //String data[]=request.getParameterValues("arraydata[]");
        jsresponse = arrayData[0] +" - ";//"Test Response!";

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
         jsresponse = ex.toString();               
        }
        resp.getWriter().write(jsresponse);
    }
```

It returns null values

Comment: rectify what? You need to define a specific problem and tell us what part is or isn't working. Just dumping some code in a post and saying `fix it` won't get you any help

Comment: See I said servlet return null. there is no error but servlet not getting data

Comment: I used $.ajax function its working well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var files = $('#files').prop("files");

var reader = new FileReader();

var data = new Array();

reader.readAsText(files[0]);

reader.onload = function(event){

```
   var csv = event.target.result;

    data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
```

$.post("UploadCSVServlet",{arraydata:data,mode:"Insert"},

function(data) {

```
alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
```

});

};

}); });

I use this. now its working

just end bracket put after function(data).

Thanks for all.